# Circuit help required - press two buttons to trigger third input using common ground fightstick board

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

I have a gaming fightstick which I don't want to install any additional buttons into. I need help with connection or a circuit so when I press two buttons (eg select & start), it triggers a third input (eg Guide/Home) or A+B=C. I still need the individual functionality of the buttons though.

I have tried using an AND gate and NPN transistors but I couldn't get it to work because of the way most controller boards are designed. They all use a common ground in that when you press the button, it pulls the voltage to ground instead of allowing a voltage through.

Is this even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You want low_A AND low_B = Low_C

This can *probably* be implemented with two cheap NPN transistors, 2 diodes and 3 resistors. I say probably because your description may not cover all that is actually involved.

Q2 is usually off so Button C = high = off
Q1 is usually ON and holds Q2 base low so Q2 is off.

---

If Button A and/or Button B are off their voltage is high and D1 and/or D2 convey the high via R1 to Q1 base turning it on so that Q2 is off.

If Button A AND Button B are ON their voltages are both low so neither D1 or D2 convey a high via R1 to Q1 base so Q1 base is low, Q1 is off, R2 pulls Q2 base high, Q2 is on, Q2 collector is on, Button C output is low/on.

Resistor values are probably about right.
A 100k from Q1 base to ground may be helpful to keep Q1 off.

Transistors shownare suitable but almost any small NPN will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBWVMX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Champion! Thank you very much.

First I tested this on my bread board then soldered it up properly on some vero board. BTW, I didn't need the 100k resistor, it seems to work perfectly the way it is.

Thank you again.

Comment: @Dreamcazman I'm glad it worked for you. The 100k is a "safety measure" which may make a difference if the board is contaminated / dusty / high humidity. Without it Q1 base MAY be pulled high by Q1 leakage and odd leakage from elsewhere. Many people do not include this. || If you are involved with other people using similar then you are welcome to pass this on / share with a group / whatever.  || Link to this answer is https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/648347/3288 || For link to question substitute /q/ for the /a/